# I cannot figure out what date format this is

Tags: icalendar

I've got these ical files I'm trying to process and they come with microsoft teams links. The invites have this very strange format for the date that I just can't figure out. I thought it was UTC but I still can't seem to figure it out. Any calendaring program opens it just fine, showing me the correct date. But I want to process the text.

Here is an example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Central Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
```

This one in particular converts to October 27, 2021 at 3:00pm Central Daylight time. I could process things another way, but I have to satisfy my curiosity here. I tried to look at the RFC for ICS but I haven't seen what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Those are daylight saving changes for the timezone component. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.6.5

"DTSTART" in this usage MUST be specified as a date with a local time value.

For local time value, see Form#1 for DATETIME https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#page-33

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If those are local time values then I don't see a 27 in there. I don't see a 28 or a 26 for that matter. So I have to assume it's UTC, but that does not convert to anywhere near the right date using the UTC converters available online. I'll keep looking into it